# GDAL C# Error: "Failed to import coordinate system"

Tags: gdal, c#

I've been struggling with building C# code that will do the equivalent of `gdalwarp`, specifically reproject a GeoTIFF file and save to an ESRI .bil file (EHdr)

To that end, I thought the following code might do the trick:

```
var vrt = Gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(srcDs, null, epsg5070, ResampleAlg.GRA_Average, 0.0);
var bilfile = bilDriver.CreateCopy(dstPath, vrt, 1, null, null, null);
```

where `epsg5070` is the WKT for EPSG:5070.  The source GeoTIFF is EPSG:4269.

The AutoCreateWarpedVRT statement errors with:

```
Failed to import coordinate system `GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"],EXTENSION["CENTER_LONG",-96.5]]'.
```

The WKT in the error is 4269, the projection of the source file.

I am using the NuGet packages (GDAL / GDAL.Native, v2.4.4), have called the GdalConfiguration methods, the GDAL files appear to be copied correctly to the project output (including the gdal/data and gdal/share folders), and it appears the paths are being set correctly.  But my impression is that GDAL is not finding its data.

Where should I look next?  Is there a trick I don't know about?  Or am I going about this the wrong way? 
 I'd rather not shell out to the command-line utilities.

Comment: I wonder what that extension part means. Gdalsrsinfo returns this `gdalsrsinfo epsg:4269 -o wkt_esri

GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
    DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  I do know that `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:5070 -of EHdr -r average srcfile dstfile` works just fine.

Comment: Source WKT looks like different yours here https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83/html/ . If you have chance it is easy to implement with ArcGIS Pro and C#.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was incorrect WKT string. There are two solutions:

1. `gdalsrsinfo -o wkt_simple epsg:5070 > epsg5070.prj`

   And then load the PRJ file, or use it directly as const string, or
2. ```
   var sr = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(null);
   sr.ImportFromEPSG(5070);
   sr.ExportToWkt(out var epsg5070);
   ```

And use it directly.

Code sample.

[image]

CRS of input data (fstopo.tif)

[image]

CRS of output data (abc) *(Reason for `-o wkt1` is to fit screen for capture.)*

[image]